# How to limit nubmer of Foreign key relations in Django ORM?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have a model which is recursively related to itself. It's content is as follows.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        path = [self.name, ]
        node = self.parent
        while node is not None:
            path.append(node.name)
            node = node.parent
        return '->'.join(path[::-1])
```

What I want to achieve is a little validation that prevents more than 3 children to parent Category.
For example if I create as state above, it will be saved as follows:

`Programming->Back-end->Python->ifelse.`

**My question**: How can I prevent parent category to have more then 3 children?

Comment: I'm confused: are you asking that it should not be possible to create the category "ifelse" above, or that category "Python" can not have more than 3 children ("ifelse", "for", "while", but not "trycatch")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        if self.parent:
            if self.get_parents_length(self) > 3:
                raise ValidationError("Parent has already got 3 children!")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        path = [self.name, ]
        node = self.parent
        while node is not None:
            path.append(node.name)
            node = node.parent
        return '->'.join(path[::-1])

    @staticmethod
    def get_parents_length(cat):
        parents = [cat.name]
        node = cat.parent
        while node is not None:
            parents.append(node.name)
            node = node.parent
        return len(parents)
```

Comment: Just put this in save(). Don't call `full_clean` inside save: best case it'll be called twice, worst case it will do model validation where it is not wanted (for example in signals).

Comment: @Melvyn, the best client I can think of is in views just as doc put, could you help to explain, why this will be called twice if put full_clean inside save

Comment: @minglyu I have checked that did not really work but I got the idea thanks, I will edit some little changes to your answer and accept it. Thanks

Comment: @minglyu full_clean is called by model forms. In cases of for example a user profile model, where one is automatically created by a signal handler, the validation is often stricter than the database restrictions. Calling full_clean() inside save() will then prevent the profile model to be created.

Comment: is there any easier way that I can get the first parent from child category in above code. As it is always testing from its one step higher parent it is never going to raise ValidaitonError. I was thinking if it possible to it without looping.

Comment: @Madiyor I think you better implement `Category` using third party library like `django-mptt` which implemented sophisticated data-structures for `tree` like object, recursing like this is very inefficient

Comment: @Melvyn thanks for your explanation, from my previous understanding,  put `full_clean`  before the `save` serves as a line of defense for data Integrity, because the `clean` method and other field level validations may be easily forget from other client.

Comment: @minglyu do you think it will be inefficient even if I have max of three sub categories? (just did not want to use third party library)

Comment: In this case, I don't think you will have problems for single object retrieve/creation, but you may have troubles for complex filtering, which would result many queries in single operation, `mptt` use `nested set` and some other data structures to implenet the tree in relational db. so you can accomplish most of the tasks in a single query, it's worth to take a look imo.